# Accessing individual properties from Realm database RLMResults - SWIFT

Tags: database, swift, dictionary, realm

I want to know the best way to access individual properties from RLMResults. I have a Realm "Jobs" database containing several properties i.e jobTitle, jobDescription, jobStartedDate. I've got an array that I query and the query returns the jobs from the database. I want to know how I could access the individual properties, say "jobTitle" only and print to the console.

```
 for job in reportedJobsPDF  {

    var titles = Jobs.objectsWhere("jobTitle == '\(job)' ")


   println("\(titles)")


    }
```

This returns output to console as below:

```
RLMResults <0x7ff5dbd38790> (
[0] Jobs {
    jobDescription = 34 desc;
    jobTitle = New jobs 34;
    jobStarted = 2014-11-28 21:14:24 +0000;

}
```

I want to be able to access those properties individually or is it possible to add the results to a swift dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `RLMResults.count` to get the count of your results, and `RLMResults.objectAtIndex` to get individual objects:

```
    for job in reportedJobsPDF  {
        var titles = Jobs.objectsWhere("jobTitle == '\(job)' ")
        var firstJob = titles.objectAtIndex(0) as Jobs
        println("\(firstJob.jobTitle)")
    }
```